# python manage.py runserver not working in pycharm

Tags: python, django, server, pycharm, manage.py

[image: manage.py not working Django not opening how to fix it?]
django isn’t working in pycharm

Comment: hi there. from the same directory, can you run `pip freeze` and paste the output here?

Comment: did you followed exactly these steps while creating your project ? link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380933/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-problem-in-vs-code/61393915#61393915

Answer (score 2):

You have to change run-configuration and project interpreter setting in pycharm CE.

Step1 : file -> settings - > choose your python interpreter

Step2 : run -> edit configuration -> click on + button -> you can see configurations in 
        window right side

Step3: In script path give your project manage.py path 
       ex:`C:\Users\sachan\backend\backend\manage.py`

Step4: In parameter add `runserver`

Step5: select your python interpreter

Make sure you have installed all the required python packages

Answer (score 1):

Top right corner Add Configuration and add the paths and commands as in the picture
(Assuming there is no issue in the python path or environment variables of the system)
[image]