# Python Django , Couldn't import Django?

Tags: python, django

I have been learning django 3.x and I set up all necessary staff.

I activated my virtual enviroment and it works, but when I try to run this command it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dzhiv\Dev\django-bootcamp\manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dzhiv\Dev\django-bootcamp\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\dzhiv\Dev\django-bootcamp\manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

- I have python on path enviroment.(If I had not, cmd would not show me
  when I type python) I created virtual envrioment(python -m venv . ) I
  started django project(django-admin startproject ...) I activate
  virtual enviroment with (.\Scripts\activate) and it works. When I run
  this (python manage.py createsuperuser) command I get errors.

So I am on a windows 10 pc and I used powershell or VsCode's terminal(same, I know).

What should I do ?

Comment: Did you install `Django` in the virtual environment?

Comment: You should activate the environment, and run `pip install Django`.

Comment: Of course mr.  I run some django commands there (django-admin startproject) and I am sure that django works.

Comment: but the `django-admin` is *not* part of the `Django` python package. That is simply a program that constructs files, but it does not include the Python library.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, you did not install Django in the virtual environment. After activating the virtual environment, you install this with:

```
# activated virtual environment
pip install Django
```

Note that the `django-admin` command, is *not* part of the Django library in Python. This is essence just a command that will create some files in the directory. Furthermore even if you installed the Django Python library *globally*, then it is not (per se) installed in the local environment. The idea of a local environment is that you run a dedicated Python version with a dedicated set of packages, not the ones installed globally on the system.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem , Thank you for your time and I figured out what I skipped in process.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can find your problem solution at below link
at this community already the answer is given to this kind of problem
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' problem in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380933/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-problem-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the command `pip install django` after activating your virtual environment. Then you can run the django-admin commands successfully.

Answer (score 0):

activate your virtual environment by writing in cmd
workon yourenvname then
write
pip install django